# How can I count the number of values by group in excel

Tags: excel

I was wondering if there was a way to count the number of values by category. Example:

A 3

A 3

A 3

B 4

B 4

B 4

B 4

C 5

C 5

C 5

C 5

C 5

D 2

D 2

What is happening there is that there are 5 categories "A, B, C, D" and there are different counts of it. Duplicate values. I would like to create a new column and output the number of times it occurs in a different column as shown above. Please no VBA as i don't know it.

Comment: What's the fifth category? Try pivot tables.

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
=IF(A2<>A1,COUNTIF(A:A,A2),"")
```

[image]